# Qt release application don't see plugin

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

I have a problem with release application, it is don't see psql driver if i start it by exe from explorer.
But it works perfect if i start it from visual studio...

I place these files near exe, and no result:

```
unins000.dat
msvcp140.dll
qsqlpsql.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5Sql.dll
vccorlib140.dll
Server.exe
unins000.exe
config.json
```

error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC ODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

but i compiled that plugin defore!

Whats can be wrong?

Comment: Run it in Dependency Walker and see if you're missing any DLLs.

Comment: @MrEricSir it is show nothing critical

Comment: @ExiD , You need to use [Dependency Walker Application Profiling](http://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/application_profiling.htm) to detect dependencies dynamically (as they are being loaded at run-time). Most likely you will find out that you need to copy `libpq.dll`, `libintl.dll` to your application's directory. . .

Answer (score 1):

To deploy qt application with plugins you should also add plugins in same folder as application. [How to deploy qt applications with plugins](http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=138)

You should also add platform folder near application to be able to deploy your application on computers where qt isn't available.

[image: Here is an example of my application]
It's on Linux but same applies in windows. You can only add sqldrivers in plugins folder.

```
qt.conf file contaians:

[Paths]
Plugins=plugins
```

Also run Dependency Walker to find all dependent libraries.